# Get value of selected dropdown in table cell using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table whose second column is a dropdown list. I want to grab the value of the dropdown. The problem I am having now is that if a user selects the value of the second row's drop down list, I am still receiving the value of the first row's dropdown list.

Here's my code:

```
$('#orders').on('change', function () {

    console.log("value is " + $('.dropdown_select').closest("tr").find("option:selected").val());
});
```

My table is is "#orders" and my dropdown select class name is "dropdown_select".

Can anyone show me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Shouldn't the on change function apply to the drop down selector, not the table? `$('.dropdown_select').on('change', function() { console.log($(this).val()) });`

Comment: I've added a sample as fiddle in my answer. You can check the result as online now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$('#orders').on('change', '.dropdown_select' , function () {
     console.log("value is " + $(this).find(":selected").val());
});
```

**Big benefit of this way is if you add new rows to your table later (dynamically), this still works fine.**

---

You can [try this online](http://jsbin.com/vuvaxemiti/1/edit) or change it and look at the result.

---

**Why your code not working fine??**

Because `$(".dropdown_select").closest(...)` returns all `.dropdown_select` elements and when you call `.closest(..)` on it, `jQuery` returns closest of first item always.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time out explaining the reason why my code failed. I will surely post the html next time. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome @bangbang. I'm glad the problem was resolved :) . Please pay attention to `Big benefit` part certainly.  Also, you can upvote and accept both if my answer was helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. The benefit part is certainly very helpful as I am adding rows dynamically. Also, if I want to get nth column value when a user selects the drop down, how can I do it? I have been trying to do it like this: 
  lineTotal = table.row($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(7)')).text()); but am getting a type error ( TypeError: table.row(...).text is not a function)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to bind the change event to the selects, not the table itself. This should work for you:

```js
$('.dropdown_select').on('change', function () {
    console.log("value is " + $(this).find("option:selected").val());
    // In fact, it would be even better if you get the val with " $(this).val()" as suggested by sideroxylon
});
```

Remember to provide the HTML next time!